# Switched 5V Power Source XBox 360

Tags: 5v, motherboard

I am looking for a 5V power source for some LEDs that I want to put in my XBox 360 slim.
I have soldered them to 5V on the USB ports, but they have constant power, and I only want power when the console is on.  Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe one of the hdmi pins has 5V when the box is on,  maybe the fan? is there a power indicator?

Comment: The fan is 12v. Ill check the hdmi tomarrow.

Comment: perhaps reconfigure the leds for 12V, usually it just means a different resistor, gives the option to  put them in series saving power.

Comment: @Jasen or use that 12V rail to switch transistor which will switch 5V rail to LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

As Jasen commented, you can put some LEDs in series and run them from your 12V Fan supply.

E.g. 5 x 2.2V LEDs in series = 11V so you need to drop 1V at say 15mA so the current limiting resistor would be 1/0.015 = 66 ohms or thereabouts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f23aNW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea in Chupacrabras' comment would be to use the 12V fan supply to turn on the LEDS while powering them from 5V. I think that might look something like this (untested)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDN4pt.png)</sup>

The above values should be OK for small indicator LEDs with a forward voltage of 2.2V and a working current of 10-20mA. If you are planning to floodlight an arena from your XBox, you'd have to respecify and recalc.